# Open page within current page using onsen ui segment control

Tags: onsen-ui

I am using **Segment control** in my App but I am **unable to switch between the segments.**

I am referring this link https://onsen.io/pattern-schedule.html

I have tried and also searched a lot **but cant find any solution**.

**My Output :**

[image]

**My Code :**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/onsenui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/onsen-css-components.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sliding_menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<script src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/onsenui.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>js"></script>

</head>
<script>
   ons.bootstrap();
</script>
<body>

<ons-navigator animation="slide" title="Navigator" var="menu">
 <ons-page var ="variable">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        Menu
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button>
          <ons-icon icon="ion-plus" fixed-width="false" style="vertical-  
             align: -4px;"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>


  <div class="navigation-bar">
      <div class="navigation-bar__center">


        <div class="button-bar" style="width:100%;right:8px; margin:8px; padding: 0px 5px;">

          <div class="button-bar__item" ngclick="menu.setMainPage('indian.html')">
            <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a" checked>
            <div class="button-bar__button">Indian</div>
          </div>

          <div class="button-bar__item" ngclick="menu.setMainPage('english.html')">
            <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a">
            <div class="button-bar__button">English</div>
          </div>

           <div class="button-bar__item" ngclick="menu.setMainPage('drinks.html')"> 
            <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a">
            <div class="button-bar__button">Drinks</div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
 </div>

 </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="indian.html">

 <ons-page>
  <div>
    Hello, this is the content of drinks.html
  </div>
 </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="english.html">

<ons-page>
 <div>
   Hello, this is the content of drinks.html
 </div>
</ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="drinks.html">
<ons-page>
 <div>
   Hello, this is the content of drinks.html
 </div>
</ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Thanks in Advance.

**Edit :**

*My requirements is that I want to open the templates i.e indian.html ,english.html and drinks.html within the same page on segment control click respectively like the splitview does*

*I am using Onsen 1*

*I am not using Sliding menu.*

**Update:I am now getting this Error...**

```
 04-11 04:58:06.471 14813-14851/com.hogo.onsenui E/AndroidProtocolHandler:    
 Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/english.html
 04-11 04:58:06.501 14813-14813/com.hogo.onsenui I/chromium:   
 [INFO:CONSOLE(108)] "Error: Page is not found: english.html
                                                            at  
  file:///android_asset/www/js/onsenui.js:13828:17
                                                            at  
  file:///android_asset/www/js/angular/angular.min.js:120:182
                                                            at n.$eval  
  (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular/angular.min.js:134:493)
                                                            at n.$digest 

  (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular/angular.min.js:132:9)
                                                            at n.$apply 
  (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular/angular.min.js:135:269)
                                                            at l 
  (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular/angular.min.js:87:152)
                                                            at F 
  (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular/angular.min.js:91:187)
                                                            at 
   XMLHttpRequest.e  
   (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular/angular.min.js:92:271)", source: 
   file:///android_asset/www/js/angular/angular.min.js (108)
```

**Updated Code :**

```
 <body>
   <ons-tabbar var="navi" position="top">
   <ons-tab page="indian.html" active="true"></ons-tab>
   <ons-tab page="english.html"></ons-tab>
   <ons-tab page="drinks.html"></ons-tab>
   </ons-tabbar>


<ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        Menu
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button>
          <ons-icon icon="ion-plus" fixed-width="false" style="vertical-  
                align: -4px;"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
  </ons-toolbar>

 <ons-page>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
      <div class="navigation-bar__center">

        <div class="button-bar" style="width:100%;right:8px; margin:8px; 
             padding: 0px 5px;">

          <div class="button-bar__item" ng-click="navi.setActiveTab(0)">
            <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a" checked>
            <div class="button-bar__button">Indian</div>
          </div>

          <div class="button-bar__item" ng-click="navi.setActiveTab(1)">
            <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a">
            <div class="button-bar__button">English</div>
          </div>

           <div class="button-bar__item" ng-click="navi.setActiveTab(2)"> 
            <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a">
            <div class="button-bar__button">Drinks</div>
          </div>

          </div>

         </div>
       </div>
    </ons-page>


<ons-template id="indian.html">

 <ons-page>

  <p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">
    english Contents
  </p>
   </ons-page>

 </ons-template>

<ons-template id="english.html">

  <ons-page>

  <p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">
    english Contents
  </p>
  </ons-page>

 </ons-template>

<ons-template id="drinks.html">

  <ons-page>

  <p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">
    drinks Contents
  </p>
  </ons-page>

 </ons-template>

  </body>
```

I have hide the tabbar in my css page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues which may be preventing the program from working:

1. You are including angular twice

   ```
   <script src="js/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   ```

   It's probably not the cause of your problem, but it may cause other issues - only one of the two files is enough.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>js"></script>
   ```

   This also shouldn't be a problem, but tags like this may cause issues - when you have extra closing tags it's fine, but if you had an extra open tag then the whole page could be blank.
2. The attributes should be `ng-click`, not `ngclick`.
3. If you want to use the `ons-navigator` then the methods you have available are `pushPage, popPage, replacePage`. The `setMainPage` method which you're using is a method of the `ons-sliding-menu`.

If you want to have data filtered then you should:

1. Add `ng-controller="AppController"` to the body or some other parent element.
2. Add `ng-model="a"` to the radio buttons (and i guess some values).
3. Add the items to the `$scope` in the controller.
4. Add `ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { category: category }"` or something similar

So something like:

```
<div class="navigation-bar">
  <div class="navigation-bar__center">
    <div class="button-bar" style="width:100%;right:8px; margin:8px; padding: 0px 5px;">
      <div class="button-bar__item">
        <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a" ng-model="a" value="indian" checked>
        <div class="button-bar__button">Indian</div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-bar__item">
        <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a" ng-model="a" value="english">
        <div class="button-bar__button">English</div>
      </div>
       <div class="button-bar__item"> 
        <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a" ng-model="a" value="drinks">
        <div class="button-bar__button">Drinks</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ons-list ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { category: category }">
    <ons-list-item>{{item.name}} ...</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

And for javascript:

```
ons.bootstrap().controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.a = "indian";
  $scope.items = [ // put your items here
    name: 'item 1', category: 'indian',
    name: 'item 2', category: 'indian',
    name: 'item 3', category: 'english',
    name: 'item 4', category: 'english',
    name: 'item 5', category: 'drinks',
    name: 'item 6', category: 'drinks'
  ]
});
```

**Update:** I thought you wanted filtering. I'll leave the previous answer if anyone else is interested in it. And now the answer to the updated question:

What you seem to want in that case is exactly the functionality of `ons-tabbar` - you have tabs and tab contents - exactly what you seem to want. So you just want to have different styles for the tabs.

However styling them in that way may not be trivial and moreover the styles may break if you try to update the version. So instead I'll provide 2 other solutions, which don't require advanced css tricks:

1. Use a tabbar, but just hide it and link the actions from your segment control:

   ```
   <div class="button-bar">
     <div class="button-bar__item" ng-click="navi.setActiveTab(0)">
       <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a" checked>
       <div class="button-bar__button">Indian</div>
     </div>
     ...
     <div class="button-bar__item" ng-click="navi.setActiveTab(2)">
       <input type="radio" name="navi-segment-a">
       <div class="button-bar__button">Drinks</div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <ons-tabbar var="navi" position="top">
     <ons-tab page="indian.html" active="true"></ons-tab>
     <ons-tab page="english.html"></ons-tab>
     <ons-tab page="drinks.html"></ons-tab>
   </ons-tabbar>
   ```

   CSS:  `#navi .tab-bar { display: none; }`
2. Just use the navigator if you want to change the pages.

   - `<ons-navigator page="indian.html" id="navi"></ons-navigator>`
   - Add `ng-click="navi.replacePage('pagename.html')"` to the `.button-bar__item`s
   - Add some distance on the top side of the navigator `#navi { top: 40px; }`

Comment: @llia Yatchev thanks for you reply, I have edited my question please see it

Comment: @AshishShukla I appended the new solution for the updated question. I left the old one in case anyone else is interested

Comment: I have followed your answer but getting Page not found error .Can you please check whats wrong ...I have updated my question ..Thanks

Comment: well you shouldn't update your question in that case since the error which you are getting is a completely different one. It just means that it wasn't able to find the page from the template and then it tried to find it as a separate file and failed. Generally this shouldn't happen unless there is a typo somewhere, but I guess maybe for some reason it wasn't able to find it. I have made a working [__demo__](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/wGmBRQ). Please check it. ^_^ __Sidenote__: the structure which you should have is something like `ons-page > ons-toolbar + .button-bar + ons-tabbar`.

Comment: @llia Yatchev Thanks i found your code working fine as i wanted in codepen but when i added it to my html file the english tab is not working and giving page not found error...Can you guess what would be the problem..

Comment: Well either a typo or some improper tag closing is what comes to mind. You can try to inspect it and see if there is a problem with the template. You could check the results of the following 3 lines.
`document.querySelector('ons-tab[page="english.html"]') document.querySelector('ons-template[id="english.html"]') document.querySelector('ons-template[id="english.html"]').template`
And another option for now is just for example copy drinks twice and name it drinks2 and start changing it so that it works. It's better if we find the cause, but otherwise this can be an easy solution.